# How can I modify ripple color when using ?attr/selectableItemBackground as background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-appcompat

I've seen some SO questions and they gave some possible methods to achieve what I want. For example:

1. Use `colorControlHighlight` attribute in styles.xml.

   Here is my styles-v21.xml:

   ```
   <style name="SelectableItemBackground">
       <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#5677FC</item>
       <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
   </style>
   ```

   And my widget:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_take_photo_as_bt"
       android:layout_width="280dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:text="@string/act_take_photo"
       style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"/>
   ```

   And it doesn't work. I also tried to add `parent="Theme.AppCompat` to "SelectableItemBackground" style, or change to `colorControlHighlight(no android: prefix)"`, or change to `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`, neither is useful.
2. Use `backgroundTint` attribute in layout.

   So I add `android:backgroundTint="#5677FC"` to my `TextView`. Still useless. Then I tried to change `android:backgroundTintMode` to `src_in` and `src_atop`, and they never make a difference.

So, how can I change ripple color when I use `?attr/selectableItemBackground` as background. I only focus on Lollipop and above. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Finally I find the solution: instead of using `android:colorControlHighlight` directly in theme `SelectableItemBackground`, I should write another style:

```
<style name="SelectableItemTheme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_color</item>
</style>
```

Then:

```
<style name="SelectableItemBackground">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/SelectableItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

Finally add `style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"` to `View` in layout.xml.

**UPDATED ON 2016/8/26**
After N's release, I found that sometimes we cannot use this method to set ripple color for some kind of `View`(for example, the `CardView`). Now I highly recommend developers using `RippleDrawable`, which can also be declared in xml. Here is an example:

I want to show a ripple effect when user touches/clicks a `CardView` above API21, and of course there should be another kind of feedback before Lollipop. So I should write:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/selectable_item_background"/>
```

and `selectable_item_background` in `drawable` folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_clicked" />
</selector>
```

`selectable_item_background` in **`drawable-v21`** folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_black" />
</selector>
```

finally, the `ripple_black` in `drawable`(or `drawable-v21`) folder:

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/color_clicked"
    tools:ignore="NewApi" /> <!--you can remove this line if it's in v21 folder-->
```

That's it. For other views, maybe you should use  `android:background="@drawable/selectable_item_background"`. Don't forget to set an `OnClickListener`, `OnTouchListener` or something like those for them, otherwise ripple won't show.

Comment: Use ```colorControlHighlight``` instead of ```android:colorControlHighlight``` works better for me, otherwise it's only for v21+

Comment: This is not the right answer, please see @harrane's answer below.

Comment: In case you've not set a ClickListener, just make the view clickable `clickable="true"` and the ripple effect will work

Answer (score 68):

### Ripple effect on pre- and Lollipop+ devices

harrane and Liuting are right. The accepted answer is not the best way.
Let me show in code how to change ripple color for **pre-Lollipop** versions and higher

1. Your AppTheme should inherit from any AppCompat theme and contain colorControlHighlight attribute (without 'android:' prefix)

   ```
   <!-- Application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">#40ffffff</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Your view should contain clickable="true" (or should have a click listener set programmatically)  and background should be "?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" or "?attr/selectableItemBackground" :

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   ...
   android:clickable="true"
   android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>
   ```

Note: that if your parent view has white background you won't see ripple effect since it's white. Change colorControlHighlight value for a different color

Also, if you want different ripple colors on different activities you can set personal theme for each activity in Manifest file, for example:

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.GalleryActivity"
        android:theme="@style/RedRippleTheme"
        />
```

---

### Different ripple colors for different fragments in the same activity?

You can change attributes of Activity Theme for each fragment in runtime. Just overwrite them before fragment was inflated with your custom style and apply to a current Theme:

in **values/styles.xml**

```
    <style name="colorControlHighlight_blue">
       <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/main_blue_alpha26</item>
    </style>
```

Then, in your fragment before inflation in `onCreateView()`:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.colorControlHighlight_blue, true); //blue ripple color
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
       return view;
    }
```

This style will work only for this fragment

---

### Different ripple color for different Views? (Lollipop +)

You can change the ripple color for each view seperately using 
`colorControlHighlight` attribute, it **doesn't work** if you apply them to a view directly:

```
    <TextView
     ...
     colorControlHighlight="#40ffffff"/> <!-- DOESN'T WORK -->
```

you should apply it as a theme:

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:theme="@style/colorControlHighlight_blue"/>
```

---

P.S. Also, sometimes this approach helps if you have unknown issues with ripple and you can't figure it out. 
In my case, I used 3rd party sliding lib which messed up ripple effects for the entire layout and adding explicitly this theme to all clickable views worked out for me.

Answer (score 16):

It's showing ripple effect with color on API +21, and simple gray background on press for  API -21.
Add this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyRipple">
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_color</item>
   <item name="android:background">?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>
```

And set it to the view:

```
<Button
   ...
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyRipple" />
```

Comment: It's important to notice that it's indeed as you wrote `android:theme` and not what people usually use `style` .

Answer (score 13):

Use the below steps:

```
1. Make changes to button view in your layout.xml
2. Add new styles in styles.xml
```

your_layout.xml

```
<Button
                        android:id="@+id/setup_submit_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

> -The style attribute calls the style that we created.
>
> -Foreground attribute calls the andorid's default selectable attribute.

styles.xml

```
 <style name="SelectableItemTheme">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    </style>


    <style name="SelectableItemBackground">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/SelectableItemTheme</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: work for CardView, thanks

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is wrong.

The correct way to use is what Liuting mentioned in the comment.
Use `colorControlHighlight` instead of `android:colorControlHighlight` for changing the default `colorControlHighlight` from `AppCompat`

*** Please refer to http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html in the Theming section ***

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to create a ripple:

```
public static void setRippleDrawable(View view, int normalColor, int touchColor) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = new RippleDrawable(ColorStateList.valueOf(touchColor), view.getBackground(), null);
            view.setBackground(rippleDrawable);
        } else {
            StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
            stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(touchColor));
            stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(touchColor));
            stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(normalColor));
            view.setBackground(stateListDrawable);
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + e);
    }
}
```

I did not found any way to modify the selectableItemBackground attribute.
That's why I did it like above.

Answer (score 0):

In dark black theme(Or any other) app try to use like below
first create `ripple_effect.xml` in `drawable` folder and add code like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#f5f5f5">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f5f5f5" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

then set background to your Any view like `Linear layout, Button, TextView` etc.

```
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvApply"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="APPLY"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:focusable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml set background:

```xml
<View
    android:id="@+id/click_view"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" <!-- Set ripple this way -->
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

And in your code change color of it:

```kotlin
// Take borderless ripple
val ripple = clickView.background as? RippleDrawable 

// Change color here
ripple?.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED))
```

Don't know how it works with Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, this solution I've worked on should work at least for most of the cases:

```
fun View.setBackgroundTintColor(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    val background = background
    if (background is RippleDrawable) {
        val newBackground = background.mutate() as RippleDrawable
        if (color != 0)
            newBackground.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
        this.background = newBackground
    } else {
        if (color == 0)
            ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(this, null)
        else
            ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
yourView.setBackgroundTintColor(0xffff0000.toInt())
```

And to reset to normal:

```
yourView.setBackgroundTintColor(0)
```

As you can see, you should know that using it might make the View have a new background, sadly.

Answer (score -1):

Use the foreground attribute as selectableItemBackground
and background attribute as the color you want.

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
```

Comment: By doing it like this, you will not have a option to change the ripple effect color. The question - `How can I modify ripple color when using ?attr/selectableItemBackground as background?`