# Transparent/translucent Activity on top of another activity having orange Background onClick

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity on top of another. I am using the below code as theme in the manifest file.

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

It works totally fine. But click on any part of view has a orange background as selected area.

This is how it looks.

[image]
[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick fix by overriding background as custom drawable to all of my views present in that activity. But I want to follow a standard.

Here's how the code looks like.

I created a drawable called selectable_background for android below 21.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:drawable="@color/color_clicked" />
</selector>
```

for android 21 and above

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_black" />
</selector>

<ripple
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/color_clicked"/>
```

and added to all the views

```
android:background="@drawable/selectable_item_background"
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061050/how-can-i-modify-ripple-color-when-using-attr-selectableitembackground-as-backg?answertab=votes#tab-top)