# No Ripple Effect in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, rippledrawable

I am using `RecyclerView` to display quote list `Fragment`. I am trying to use Ripple effect in list item but its not working. My `RecyclerView` is like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listQuoteView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/BackColor"
        android:layout_above="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And List Item XML is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/quoteActionView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/TextColor"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageAuthorView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/imageAuthorView"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/imageAuthorView"
                android:visibility="visible" />



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textQuote"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_text_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_text_margin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/linespace"
                    android:textColor="?attr/MainTextColor"
                    android:text="Hello there two line text for show here which I am typing for a test"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textDetailQuote"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="?attr/dark_color"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/likeIcon"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/likeIcon"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:tint="?attr/List_Text"
                        android:src="@drawable/time_new_ic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblTimeCount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:text="00:00"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="?attr/List_Text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/lblTime" />



                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/likeIcon"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/likeIcon"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:tint="?attr/List_Text"
                        android:src="@drawable/fav_new_ic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblLikeCount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="200"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="?attr/List_Text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/lblTime" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/likeIcon"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/likeIcon"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:tint="?attr/List_Text"
                        android:src="@drawable/share_new_ic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblShareCount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:textColor="?attr/List_Text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/lblTime" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried many solutions listed in stackoverflow but not worked any. **If I remove `CardView` from List Item.... Ripple Effect shows itself behind `LinearLayout` but I want to use `CardView` also.** Let me know if someone can help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

**Note :** I have solved it using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061050/how-can-i-modify-ripple-color-when-using-attr-selectableitembackground-as-backg). Thanks

Comment: make your cardview clickable and give it forgroundColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create ripple **drawable** and set it as **foreground** of your layout

**ripple.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/your_color"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Change your code like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
```

Comment: try it as foreground. I tried by setting this same code as foreground its worked for me.

Comment: See my updated answer. set ripple to cardview not for relative layout@Priya

Answer (score 3):

Set the ripple as a *foreground* drawable on the `CardView`:

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

This will allow the ripple to show up *above* the content inside the `CardView`, which is usually what you want for a `CardView`

Comment: Did you apply it on the CardView or on the RelativeLayout? It's only going to work on the CardView.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`