# how can i get the value of "colorControlHighlight" attribute at runtime?

Tags: java, android, styles, android-theme

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38533561/311130) which explains the color is set in `colorControlHighlight`

I try to verify the runtime value of this attribute `colorControlHighlight`

But not sure what's the code to check this

How can I know which index to use?

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
int[] textSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.colorControlHighlight };
int indexOfAttrTextSize = 0;
TypedArray c = view.getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, textSizeAttr);
int selectableItemBackground = c.getColor(indexOfAttrTextSize, -1);
c.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913610/3625596).

Also note that `getColorStateList(int)` has been [deprecated since Android Marshmallow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList(int)). You may prefer to use [`getColorStateList(int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList(int,%2520android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) instead.

Comment: I have looked at your post, but how can i know which index to use?

Comment: TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    int[] textSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.colorControlHighlight };
    int indexOfAttrTextSize = 0;
    TypedArray c = view.getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, textSizeAttr);
    int selectableItemBackground = c.getColor(indexOfAttrTextSize, -1);
    c.recycle();