# how to set ripple in android: `?attr/selectableItemBackground` as a background or a foreground?

Tags: android, layout, attributes, ripple

I used supprtLibrary to add ripple on an imageView.

I saw a post where they set the ripple effect using [background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54322547/311130) attribute
and another where they set the [foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041873/311130) attribute.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Both ways are ok? same effect?

Comment: `android:foreground` will work only in API 23 and above. If you want simple grey ripple just use `android:background`. If you need to have not default background and ripple effect above it then use both of them.

Comment: Thanks, how could i have found this difference btw? have a documentation link please?

Comment: `android:foreground` -  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:foreground `android:background` -  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background